# Adding parameters into formset declaration

Tags: python, django

I'm building a formset based on a few variables

```
FormSet = eval("modelformset_factory(TemplateModel, form=%s, extra=extra, max_num=max_forms, can_delete=True)" % formname)
```

I want to pass some perameters into this FormSet variable so that I can pick them up in my forms.py

```
form_kwargs={'user': user}
```

How would I add these forms_kwargs perameters into the first line of code?

Comment: Please do *not* use `eval`. It is often unnecessary, and furthermore makes applications unsafe and less predictable.

Comment: Ah, just doing some reading on this. I'll remove it. Thanks!